# subset of rationals doesn't have supremum proof understanding

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

I'm trying to understand a proof I'm reading regarding rational numbers and supremums.

(*) Every nonempty bounded from above set of real numbers **M** has a least upper bound which is denoted supM.

We'll show that (*) is not true for the set of rational numbers.

Let $M = \{x \in \mathbb Q : x^2 \le 2\}$ . The number 2 is an upper bound of M which implies that the set M is bounded from above. Let l be the least upper bound of M and lets assume that $l \in \mathbb Q$. It is clear that $l > 1$. We'll show that $l^2 < 2$ is impossible. And really, then $m=\frac{2+2l}{2+l} \in \mathbb Q$. Lets look at 
$$
2 - (\frac{2+2l}{2+l})^2 = \frac{2(2+l)^2-(2+2l)^2}{(2+l)^2}=\frac{2-l^2}{(2+l)^2} > 0
$$
Which implies that $m^2 < 2$ and $m \in \mathbb Q$. But $ m-l>0 \implies m > l$, which shows that l cannot be an upper bound of M.

From there, there's an assumption that $l > 2$ and the proof continues. I think that if I get the first part I'll understand the rest of the proof.

My questions are:

- I feel like the statement is confusing. Isn't the set of rational a subset of the set of real numbers? Is the statement poorly written or is there something I'm missing? What is the main idea of the statement and the proof?
- What's the idea of using the set M where every element is rational with square less than or equal to 2?
- Where did **m** come from in this proof?It feels like the author knew something which for me needs some derivation.

I'm sorry if my questions are somehow vague or unclear, but I'm trying to wrap my head around this statement and proof. Maybe if I get even the main idea the rest of the text will come clear to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "We'll show that $(*)$ is not true for the set of real numbers." I think you mean rational numbers here. 
"I  feel like the statement is confusing. Isn't the set of naturals a subset of the set of real numbers?" I also think you mean rational numbers here. 
The point is that if a set E satisfies $(*)$ it is not true that subsets of E still satisfies $(*)$, so it's not a contradiction that reals satisfies (*) but not the rationals. The idea is that on the reals, $\sqrt{2}$ is the least upper bound of the set considered, but since $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational there is no least upper bound on

Comment: ...rationals.does that clarify the issue?

Comment: Are you familiar with proof by contradiction?  If not that could be the source of your confusion.  Another is that the context of the statements is important here.  The set $M$ has an obvious least upper bound: $\sqrt 2$, the catch is that is not rational.  I guess that this is leading up to a justification for the formal definition of the real numbers.  Try to imagine that you did not yet know the real numbers but only the rational numbers; the set $M$ will then seem strange: it is bounded (above) but does not have a least (best) bound.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I had some mistakes, thanks for noticing. After reading your comment I think I got the idea now. So ( * ) says what it says for the real numbers, which doesn't imply the same for every bounded subset of rationals just because the rationals is a subset of $\mathbb R$. If a set A is a subset of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ doesn't it mean that the set A is a subset of $\mathbb R$. And if (*) holds true for subsets of $\mathbb R$, isn't it going to be true for A then?

Comment: There is some text missing: **(1)** "We'll show that $l^2 < 2$ is impossible... And really". **(2)** "From there, there's an assumption that $l$ ... and ".

Comment: @badjohn, Thanks! After reading your comment too I got it now. It's like looking from above (the set of real numbers) every bounded subset has a supremum. But being down in the rationals and not seeing the real numbers you wont be able to find a supremum which is a rational. I feel like ( * ) is still poorly stated. Shouldn't it be "Every nonempty bounded from above set of real numbers has a **real** least upper bound"

Comment: @Kolmin I think you are right. "And really..." did look kind of strange to me, and then just jumping on m=... For the second thing, it's me that missed to write it, I've tried to describe that the proof continues with an assumption that l > 2, which is later contradicted again.

Comment: Since you start with "set of real numbers" you have established that you are talking about real numbers so it is not usually felt necessary to repeat that.  For example, would you feel it necessary to add a second "real" to "in the real numbers, $-1$ does not have a square root"?  Many statements would get a lot more complex if we had to repeat the context all the time.  Is $5$ prime?  In the Integers yes but in the Gaussian Integers no: $5 = (2 + i)(2 - i)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you! I think I got the idea now. The only thing which I'm still not getting is where m came from, but as @Kolmin commented the proof misses some text, so I'll try to find the same statement somewhere else and see the proof there. I'll be grateful if somebody has a link to the same statement with a more detailed proof without missing parts, or can fill it   here if it's not too much.

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov: Concerning the $m$ (beyond the missing text), maybe an old question of mine with the great answers I got can be helpful. It partly deals with typical real analysis proofs that look rabbit-out-of-the-hat-ish. Here there is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428274/archimedean-property-the-use-of-the-property-in-basic-real-anaysis-proofs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion is because the statement is not very clear. It may well be misinterpreted in a way that it holds for $\mathbb Q$ as well.

What it is missing is that it should require the supremum to be in the set of real numbers, the same set as $M$ is subset of. This in turn makes the statement to be disproved to be reformulated as we would require replacement of both sets.

If we reformulate it:

> (*) Every nonempty bounded from above set $M\subset \mathbb R$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb R$ which is denoted $\sup M$.
>
> We'll show that (*) is not true if we replace both occurences of $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb Q$.

Now it's clearer why $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$ won't help as we added the requirement that $\sup M\in\mathbb Q$ by replacing $\mathbb R$. The set certainly has a least upper bound, but it's not obvious that it would be a member of $\mathbb Q$.

The reason why they consider the set $M$ of numbers with squares less than $2$ is that the supposed supremum of such set would be $\sqrt2$ which is not a rational number.

As for the magic value of $m$ we start with the structure of the proof. What we're looking for is to exclude $l^2\ne 2$, we do this by showing that if $l^2<2$ we find a larger $m\in M$ which makes $l$ not an upper bound and if $l^2>2$ we find a smaller $m$ which still is an upper bound of $M$ that is $l$ is not the least upper bound. Then when we excluded $l^2\ne 2$ we are left with $l^2=2$ which can be excluded due to Aristotle-Euclid.

Basically what we need to do in the first step construct a recursion formula for evere larger members of $M$. We know that this can be done if we have a recursion formula which limit is $\sqrt 2$. To find this we turn to numerical methods of solving equations, the secant method for solving $f(x) = x^2-2=0$ turns out to be useful here (since $f$ is convex and if we start with $f(a_0)<0$ and $f(b_0)>0$ we will get $b_j=b_0$ and $f(a_j)<0$). Taking $b_0=2$ and $a_0=l$ we get the step in the secant method:

$$m = c_1 = a_0 - {f(a_0)(b_0-a_0)\over f(b_0)-f(a_0)} = l - {f(l)(2-l)\over
(f(2)-f(l))} = l - {(l^2-2)(2-l)\over 2-(l^2 - 2)} = {2l+2\over 2+l}$$

of course knowing the properties of the secant method we know that this means that $m>l$ and $m^2<2$, but the above calculation shows this directly instead.

I guess the next step is the opposite to assume that if $l^2>2$ we find a contradiction too. Here we would turn to Newton-Raphsons method instead as it will yield points to the right of the solutions (if we start from the right).
We have $f'(x) = 2x$ so the step in NR method would be

$$m=x_1 = x_0 - {f(x_0)\over f'(x_0)} = l - {l^2-2\over 2l} = {l^2 + 2\over 2l}$$

Now doing the same trick as before we get:

$$m^2 - 2 = \left({l^2+2\over 2l}\right)^2-2 = \left({x^2-2\over 2l}\right)^2>0$$

also we can verify that $m<l$ by calculating $m-l$:

$$m-l = \cdots = {l^2-2\over 2l} > 0$$

Now we have excluded the possibilities $l^2>2$ and $l^2<2$ so what remains is only the case $l^2=2$ (which I assume you can prove has no rational solutions).

However often one doesn't do a proof this verbose since as we have seen we can given the expression of $m$ directly verify that it fulfills our requirements. That is the validity of the proof does not rely on us motivating how we found the expression for $m$ and since that is not needed in the proof that part is often left out of the proof.

Comment: Thanks! That's one problem. Another is that m kind of pops up magically or there's some text missing. The only thing left clearing out is where m came from.

Comment: I found this question which is quite close if not exact to what I'm looking regarding m. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431972/proving-a-set-in-mathbbq-that-is-bounded-above-to-have-no-largest-number-g

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov I added an explanation as for where he might have pulled the expression of $m$ from.

Answer (score 1):

The statement says that not every subset of Q has a sup in Q
indeed the sup of A is $\sqrt{2}$ which is not rational.

Imagine you have found a sup $l$ that is the "last" rational number such that $l^2<2$. The proof shows that it can be found a rational number $m$ greater than $l$, such that $m^2<2$, which is greater than $l$, so $l$ fails to be the sup.

$m$  is greater than $l$ because $l<\frac{2+2l}{2+l}$ indeed $2l+l^2<2l+2$ because $l^2<2$

and $m^2<2$ because
$$\frac{(2 l+2)^2}{(l+2)^2}<2\rightarrow 4l^2+8l+4<2l^2+8l+8$$

Hope this helps